# Edit css of cart's coupon code input

Tags: magento2.2

I use Porto theme at magento 2,

at cart page i see input text for coupon code too small (15px).
At /pub/static/version1537796083/frontend/Smartwave/porto/el_GR/css/styles-m.css is 100%

I need to edit it and change it to 220px.
But where is the css to edit it?

Comment: Don't edit the `/pub/static/` files as they will be regenerated if you deploy static content again. You need to find the class in the `porto` theme or overwrite the class in custom.css file

Comment: Thank you. It was on a .less file of template

Comment: Great :) I just posted an answer to your question, feel free to accept if it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't edit the /pub/static/ files as they will be regenerated if you deploy static content again. You need to find the class in the porto theme or overwrite the class in custom.css file.

You should find the class somewhere in a `.less` file within the theme.